# PHP JSON HTTP POST

Tags: php, json

I have a server which accepts HTTP Post request with JSON body and sends response in JSON. 
I dont know any way in PHP to do this.

I need to send a request to server with the JSON body

```
{
MyName="Hitesh"
MyPhone="8008288081"
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

The API is available in a server hosted at xyz.hitesh.com and the PHP code will be hosted at abc.test.com

Answer (score 6):

```
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$requestBody = json_decode($requestBody);

// ???

$response = array('Accepted' => 'Yes');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I am relatively new to PHP, can you help me with some more details.

Comment: $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
What is this php://input

Comment: @Hiteshwar It's a [stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) for whatever input PHP received, e.g. the body of a POST request. Think of it as a virtual file path, like `file:///path/to/some/file`, just that it doesn't really exist as a file.